# Xamarin Form textcell.contextactions text="delete"not showing in android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm new to xamarin forms and learning it through video tutorials done using iOS development Mac laptop.I'm using windows & VS2019 for Xamarin forms. When using ListView, TextCell and ContextActions, my mentuItem text="Delete" or text="Call" aren't showing up when i select a name in the android emulator. But the same action of selection a name on the iOS emulator makes two buttons("Delete" & "Call") slides out. I attached my image as well as the tutotial image. Below are the codes from the tutorial.

[image: iOSEmulatorTutorialWorking]

[image: AndroidEmulatorNotWorking]

My xaml file is `

```
                <? xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
           < ContentPage xmlns = "http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                             xmlns: x = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                             x: Class = "WarMemorial.Excercises.ListViewContextActions" >

             < ListView x: Name = "listView" >

                   < ListView.ItemTemplate >

                       < DataTemplate >

                           < TextCell Text = "{Binding Name}"
                                          Detail = "{Binding Status}" >
                            < TextCell.ContextActions >
                                < MenuItem Text = "Call" IconImageSource = "phone.png"
                                              Clicked = "Call_Clicked"
                                              CommandParameter = "{Binding .}" ></ MenuItem >
                                < MenuItem Text = "Delete"
                                              Clicked = "Delete_Clicked" IconImageSource = "trash-can.png"
                                              CommandParameter = "{Binding .}" ></ MenuItem >

                            </ TextCell.ContextActions >

                        </ TextCell >
                    </ DataTemplate >
                </ ListView.ItemTemplate >
            </ ListView >
        </ ContentPage >
```

XAML.cs

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using WarMemorial.Models;
    using Xamarin.Forms;
    using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

    namespace WarMemorial.Excercises
    {
        [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
        public partial class ListViewContextActions : ContentPage
        {
            private ObservableCollection<Contacts> _contacts;

    
            public ListViewContextActions()
            {
                InitializeComponent();                     

                _contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contacts> {
                             new Contacts { Name = "Susana" },
                          new Contacts { Name = "Sara",  Status = "let's tallk" }
                    };
                listView.ItemsSource = _contacts;
            }

             private void Call_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var contact = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as Contacts;

                DisplayAlert("Call", contact.Name, "OK");
            }

            private void Delete_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                var contact = (sender as MenuItem).CommandParameter as Contacts;
                _contacts.Remove(contact);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: on iOS, ContextActions are triggered by a swipe gesture, on Android they are triggered by a long press.

Comment: @Jason Thank you so much, I'm new to xamarin and I'm always stuck and waste my time with the android emulator when trying to mimic the same action on iOS emulator. Is there any link which can help me understand better and save time on what are the different actions that are different for android emulator and iOS operator(like swipe in iOS emulator is same as long press in android emulator)?

Comment: these are just fundamental differences in how each OS approaches UX.  It's not Xamarin specific.  I'm sure there are docs that outline the key differences, but offhand I'm not aware of any

Answer (score 0):

as @Jason said you can't get the same behavior on iOS and Android for ContextActions, on the other hand you might want to use the *experimental* [SwipeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/swipeview) which will give you the same swipe behavior on both platforms.